# iOS - CGContextStrokePath/CGContextDrawPath remove black background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, line, drawrect

I'm trying to draw a straight dashed line. I've gotten it so it draws the dashes, but this black background color remains. I've seem many answers to other questions, but none of them worked.

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-CJBEIHHJ) seems to point to the fill color and using either CGContextFillPath or CGContextDrawPath, but neither of those work and the background of the dashed line is still black.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    GLFloat lines[] = {self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.width*2};

    CGFloat grey[4] = {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(contextRef, grey);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);

    CGContextSetLineDash(contextRef, 0, lines, 2);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, self.frame.size.width);

    CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, 0, self.frame.size.height);

    CGContextDrawPath(contextRef, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

Comment: BTW, `lines` probably should be `CGFloat` just to match the expected type of `CGContextSetLineDash`.

Comment: Oops, capitalization error, not the actual cause of my problem though :)

Comment: Quite right, not your issue here. But I think you want `CGFloat`, not `GLfloat` (the former, I believe, can be `double` on Mac OS, whereas the latter looks like it's always `float`). Not an issue on iOS, tho. More of a matter of style than substance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manually adding this view to your view hierarchy, you just have to make sure you're setting the background color. For example, if you're initializing your view with `initWithFrame`, then set the background color in that method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Or, alternatively, when adding the view, set the background color there:

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

Comment: I'd just add a small precision to clear his misunderstanding of CGContextFillPath. Filling a path is litterally filling the inside of the path, thus the path should be closed (Like a square, or a circle). You can't fill a line going from top to bottom. And it certainly wouldn't help fill the whole view if the path doesn't enclose the whole view.

Comment: @Nerkatel Agreed. I'd probably just use `kCGPathStroke` when drawing a line like this, not `kCGPathFillStroke`. Also, the use of the `width` when setting the dashing of a vertical line is curious. And because the line is so wide, half of it is falling outside of the view. It's a curious implementation, but I assume he has his reasons.

Comment: I had tried setting background color in drawRect before, but I guess I was just doing it out of context? The use of width is because this line will never be more than 2 pixels wide.

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt replies :)

Comment: @DrDisc No problem. In answer to your comment, doing it in `drawRect` is too late. You want to set the background color during the configuration of the view.